# Independent dice throw

Tags: probability, dice

I need help on this question regarding dice and probability.

The question is, that a dice throws three times independently of each other. The random variable $X$ denotes the number of sides on the $i$-th throw, where $i$ is $i=1,2,3$. 
The maximum of the random variable $Y$ is given as $Y_{max}(X_i)$.

I need to find the cdf and pmf of the random variable $Y$.

I don't know how to go on with this question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is a eye? And I suppose they are just dice with 6 sides with values going from 1 to 6.

Comment: Yes exatcly, sorry about that. I've changed it now

Comment: Do mean that $Y=\max\{X_1,X_2,X_3\}$?

Comment: Yes, that it what I mean

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**:

$P\left(Y\leq k\right)=P\left(X_{1}\leq k\wedge X_{2}\leq k\wedge X_{3}\leq k\right)=P\left(X_{1}\leq k\right)P\left(X_{2}\leq k\right)P\left(X_{3}\leq k\right)$

$P\left(Y=k\right)=P\left(Y\leq k\right)-P\left(Y\leq k-1\right)$

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I understand. You need to know the maximum value of a throw with n=3 dice.

I did some time ago [a web application](http://tube.geogebra.org/student/m145280) with a similar thing where you can see it, formulas and setup: type of dice and number of them, and search for some specific probability, etc.

You can see that, by example, for

$$P(V{=}X)=\frac{1}{D^n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(X-1)^{n-k}=\frac{X^n-(X-1)^n}{D^n}$$

In this formula *V* is the maximum value of *n* throws.

The binomial coefficient represent the amount of permutations between *n* positions of dice with a value of *V* and dice with value less than *V* on the throw. The power $(X-1)^{n-k}$ represent the variations with repetition over $X-1$ possible values on $n-k$ positions.

Finally $\frac{1}{D^n}$ represent total possible throws (variations with repetition over *n* positions that can take *D* different values), so dividing cases where *V* is the maximum value of the throw between all possible cases you have it probability.

From here summing over *n*, *D* or any other parameter let to you some distribution or accumulated distribution (anti-derivative).