# Simplification of Probability of max value over n Dice throws

Tags: probability

The answer given here by Masacroso:

[Independent dice throw](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/962228/independent-dice-throw)

Shows the following relationship:

$$P(V{=}X)=\frac{1}{D^n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(X-1)^{n-k}=\frac{X^n-(X-1)^n}{D^n}$$

I understand the middle expression but I'm not sure how it can be expressed as the rhs?

I've tested it and the result is correct but I's like to be able to derive the last expression mathematically.

Sorry if this result is well known but it's not obvious to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the [Binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem),

$$
\sum_{K=0}^n \binom{n}{k} (X-1)^{n-k}
= \sum_{K=0}^n \binom{n}{k} 1^k\cdot (X-1)^{n-k}
= (1+X-1)^n = X^n
$$
Noting that your sum starts at $k=1$ instead of $0$, you have
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{K=1}^n \binom{n}{k} (X-1)^{n-k}
&= \sum_{K=0}^n \binom{n}{k} (X-1)^{n-k} -  \binom{n}{0} (X-1)^{n} \\
&=\sum_{K=0}^n \binom{n}{k} (X-1)^{n-k} -(X-1)^{n} \\
&=X^n -(X-1)^{n}
\end{align}$$
as claimed.

Comment: Really clear explanation thanks!